# Orchard CMS - Workflow Custom Activity Recipe

Tags: orchardcms-1.7, orchard-modules

Can anybody help me create a recipe that activates the custom activity that I have created?

I have a module in which I have created some custom workflow activities. I'd like those activities to be activated when I install the module so I wouldn't have to go the Workflow panel each time and create the activities.

Please, help me with this by pointing me to an example or resource that demonstrates a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using 1.7.2, Check `Orchard.Roles.Activities` or 'Orchard.Comments.Activities'.
 You need to decorate your Tasks with `[OrchardFeature("Orchard.Comments.Workflows")]`
Then in your Module.txt, add your feature Name `Orchard.Comments.Workflows` as a dependency of your module
Check `Piedone.HelpfulLibraries` from the Gallery. He does it there very nicely and the Author: Piedone is an Orchard Team member. 
Actually download the Combinator Module, that calls the HelpfulLibraries. 
That should do it. 
I am actually going to do something like it, this week. I thought that was the way.
Let me know, Cheers

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I'd download Combination Module and will took into it asap.